# How to run custom GPU tensorflow::op from C++ code?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I follow these examples to write custom op in TensorFlow:
[Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op)
[cuda_op_kernel](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/adding_an_op/cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc)
Change the function to operation I need to do.
But all the examples are tests in Python code.
I need to run the my op from c++ code, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This simple example shows the construction and the execution of a graph using [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide):

```
// tensorflow/cc/example/example.cc

#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

int main() {
  using namespace tensorflow;
  using namespace tensorflow::ops;
  Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
  // Matrix A = [3 2; -1 0]
  auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f} });
  // Vector b = [3 5]
  auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f} });
  // v = Ab^T
  auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true)); // <- in your case you should put here your custom Op
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
  ClientSession session(root);
  // Run and fetch v
  TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
  // Expect outputs[0] == [19; -3]
  LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
  return 0;
}
```

As in the Python counterpart, you first need to build a computational graph in a scope, which in this case has only a matrix multiplication in it, whose end point is in `v`. Then you need to open a new session (`session`) for the scope, and run it on your graph. In this case there is no feed dictionary, but at the end of the page there is an example on how to feed values:

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
auto a = Placeholder(root, DT_INT32);
// [3 3; 3 3]
auto b = Const(root, 3, {2, 2});
auto c = Add(root, a, b);
ClientSession session(root);
std::vector<Tensor> outputs;

// Feed a <- [1 2; 3 4]
session.Run({ {a, { {1, 2}, {3, 4} } } }, {c}, &outputs);
// outputs[0] == [4 5; 6 7]
```

<sup>All the code segments here reported come from the C++ API guide for TensorFlow</sup>

If you want to call custom OP you have to use almost the same code. I have a custom op in [this repository](https://github.com/MatteoRagni/tf.ZeroOut.gpu) that I will use as an example code. The OP has been registered:

```
REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
  .Input("to_zero: int32")
  .Output("zeroed: int32")
  .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext *c) {
    c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
    return Status::OK();
  });
```

and the Op is defined to be a Cuda Kernel in the [cuda file](https://github.com/MatteoRagni/tf.ZeroOut.gpu/blob/master/zero_out.cu.cc). To launch the Op I have to (again), create a new computational graph, register my op, open a session and make it run from my code:

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
// Matrix A = [3 2; -1 0]
auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f} });
auto v = ZeroOut(root.WithOpName("v"), A); 
std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
ClientSession session(root);
// Run and fetch v
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
```

Comment: is this the op you referring ? 
auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
if so i don't think this is what is looking for.  
i write a GPU kernel op that i what to use from c++ code
my op copy tensor to the gpu using the gpu multi thread operations

Comment: Your GPU Op is called by the Op Wrapper in C++ code. You are not allowed to call directly the kernel of the Op, it is called by the session that executes the graph. MatMul is a GPU Op (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/mat-mul).

Comment: Also, your kernel must be registered in Tensorflow in this way: https://github.com/MatteoRagni/tf.ZeroOut.gpu/blob/master/zero_out.cc

Comment: i work with zero_out example i write my kernel code like the example

Comment: thanks Matteo for the help
i work with zero_out example as wall i write my kernel code like the example, 
but i'm not at understand how to call my op, lets work with zero_ot example how can i call it from c++ code

Comment: is anybody was able to call custom op in c++ code ?

Comment: I have written a second part of the answer several days ago, but I forgot to post it. I'm really sorry. Take a look at the answer again and look if it helps you...

Comment: Tanks Matteo for the detailed example, i clone the repository build it add main.cpp file that run the code example of ZeroOut OP, I include zero_out.cc to main.cpp and link with zero_out.so, but when compiling I get error: ‘ZeroOut’ was not declared in this scope, what more is needed to successfully compile this example ?

Comment: Matteo the [repository] (https://github.com/MatteoRagni/tf.ZeroOut.gpu) have issue with the make file repository flag GPUDEF is defined but not used,  and I can't used it from C++ code can't overcome the error: ‘ZeroOut’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @matteo-ragni Would you elaborate your solution in details? I got the problem `‘ZeroOut’ was not declared in this scope`. It seems that `MatMul` class is auto generated as there is no `tensorflow/cc/ops/math_ops.h` in the github source code. Maybe the same thing should be done for ZeroOut

Comment: `tensorflow/cc/ops/math_ops.h` is in Tensorflow sources. You need the Tensorflow sources for building custom ops https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op

Comment: There is no math_ops.h under `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/cc/ops`. It's auto generated by something. The same thing should be done for `ZeroOut` in your git hub repo.