# Using new tensorflow op in a c++ library that already uses tensorflow as third party

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake, shared-libraries

That's my first time asking a question in stackoverflow. I will try my best to formulate my question properly.

I want to use a custom tensorflow op in in a c++ library, which already uses tensorflow as third party. But I just don't know how to use my custom operation in c++ code at all. I'm trying to learn that with the easy ZeroOut example from Tensroflow c++ tutorial. I registered the ZeroOut op for cpu as in https://github.com/MatteoRagni/tf.ZeroOut.gpu: compiling with make worked and I got a .so file in the usr-ops folder, where also the cc file was. Then I tried to add the ZeroOut.so file to my lib as shared library, but it didn't compile. However, before I added my custom op, registered with bazel as described in tensorflow new op tutorial, in the same way and my library compiled. Maybe because the .so file was created in ../bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/ . But in this case I'm not able to use the operation as I should. And including  ZeroOut.cpp or the .cpp files of my op in my c++ files didn't make any difference until now.

Here is my CMakeList.txt, which also creates the whole library I'm working with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Project1)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release") # Debug Release
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall                 -fopenmp")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

#-------------path of 3rd party libraries-------------
# special libs.
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem iostreams regex)
find_package(FFTW)
find_package(NLopt)
find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS CXX)

set(EXTERN_LIB_ROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rd-party)

set(TENSORFLOW_ROOT /.../tensorflow)
set(TF_INCLUDE_DIRS "${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}" "${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/bazel-  genfiles" "${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/bazel-tensorflow/external/protobuf_archive/src")

# lib dirs.
set(LUA_LIBRARIES "${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/lua/liblua53.so") #5.3.4
set(LINENOISE_LIBRARIES "${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/linenoise-ng/build/liblinenoise.so")
set(YACAS_LIBRARIES "${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/yacas/cyacas/libyacas/build/libyacas.so")


set(TF_LIBRARIES ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so
    ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/core/user_ops/tf.ZeroOut.gpu-master/zero_out.so 
${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/MyNewOp.so) 
#-------------ssl headers-------------
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    ${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/eigen
    ${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/gnuplot-iostream
    ${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/
    ${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/linenoise-ng/include
    ${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/yacas/cyacas/libyacas/include
    ${EXTERN_LIB_ROOT}/lua/src
    ${NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${FFTW_INCLUDES}
    ${TF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}) 

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "build shared library" ON)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

#-------------ssl kernel lib-------------
file(GLOB_RECURSE _src_list
    LIST_DIRECTORIES false
    RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp" "")

add_library(ssl SHARED ${_src_list})

set(SSL_LIBRARIES ${TF_LIBRARIES} ${LUA_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}     ${NLOPT_LIBRARIES} ${FFTW_LIBRARIES} ${LINENOISE_LIBRARIES} ${YACAS_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES}) #${TF_LIBRARIES}

target_link_libraries(ssl ${SSL_LIBRARIES} dl)

add_executable(Project1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Project1 ssl)
```

There is a related question, but there is no clear answer.  [How to run custom GPU tensorflow::op from C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799510/how-to-run-custom-gpu-tensorflowop-from-c-code)

What am I doing wrong? I have no experience in shared library, but maybe there are other better ways to do what I'm trying to do...? 
Can someone help me, Maybe giving an example of the required CMakeList.txt?

About the errors I got at runtime:
it was a very trivial one, just the function in my .so file couldn't be found if called with the right amount of parameters, if called with the wrong one it just didn't run. 
In the meanwhile I found a better workaround. Since I can use my custom op in python, I will embed python in my c++ library, call a python function to make the graph,which will call my custom op to build the graph. But I didn't finish yet.

Comment: It sounds a good question, but please try to reduce your problem to a single question

Comment: ok! Should I re-ask two different questions?

Comment: Yes please. It will make it much easier for fellows to answer you here. Thanks!

Comment: Ask one new question and update this one (using "edit") to minimize it to one question

Comment: Done! Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Could you also include the error messaage you saw when building?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pkg_config` it becomes very simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(tf-inference)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(TensorFlow REQUIRED tensorflow)

link_directories(${TensorFlow_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_compile_definitions(${TensorFlow_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(tf-inference inference.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tf-inference ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES})
```

However that requires your TensorFlow install has the `tensorflow.pc` file included. On MacOS: `brew install libtensorflow`  will include this file, and the above works automatically.